# Unexpected closing tag - Vetur extension

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur

Im getting a pop up error for the vetur extension in vscode

[image]

when i save a file. I couldn't find the p tag its referring to but it is really annoying the only way to disable this is by turning off the formatter in vscode. how to resolve this formatting failed error?

code line 15 - 24

```
<div class="profile__desc">
      <p class="profile__paragraph">
              <strong>{{ content['artist-name'] }}</strong>
              <br />
              <pre>{{ content['work-role']}}</pre>
              <br />
              <pre v-html="content['artist-description']"></pre>
      </p>
  <!-- /profile__desc -->
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you are missing something. Could you post your code including line 23? @Cj Oyales

Comment: line 23 is a comment

Comment: @ʎzɐɹƆ added the code

Comment: oh wait, turns out that i forgot that the pre tag is a block element and cannot be nested inside a p tag.